# what is the right way to fork a loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, for-loop, fork

So i have created server which collect data and write it into db in never ending loop.

```
server.listen(3001, () => {
doFullScan();
});

async function doFullScan() {
    while (true) {
        await collectAllData();
    }
}
```

`collectAllData()` is a method which check for available projects, loop through each project collect some data and write it into db.

```
async function collectAllData() {
    //doing soemhting
    const projectNames = ['array with projects name'];

    //this loop takes too much of time
    for(let project in projectNames){
        await collectProjectData(project);
   }
   //doing something
}
```

The problem is that whole loop is taking too much time. So i would like to speed it up by multithreading loop and use all of my computer cores on it.

How should i do it?

There is cluster library with examples on https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html but i don't want to create new servers. I want to spawn childrens, which will do a task and exit after they have done its job.

So there is `const { fork } = require('child_process');` but I'm not exactly sure how to make each fork run only `collectProjectData()` method.

Comment: Instead of waiting for `collectProjectData` one by one, you could maybe parallelize them with `Promise.all` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it natively without any third party libraries.
Right now, your `for...loop` is running each one after the other.

### Option 1

Use `Promise.all` and `.map`

```
await Promise.all(projectNames.map(async(projectName) => {
  await collectProjectData(projectName);
});
```

Note, if you use `.map`, it will kick off all of them, all at the same time, which might be too much if `projectNames` continue to grow.
This is the complete opposite of what yours is doing currently.

### Option 2

There is a middle way...running batches in sequence, but items inside each batch asynchronously.

```
const chunk = (a, l) => a.length === 0 ? [] : [a.slice(0, l)].concat(chunk(a.slice(l), l));
const batchSize = 10;
const projectNames = ['array with projects name'];

let projectNamesInChunks = chunk(projectNames, batchSize);
for(let chunk of projectNamesInChunks){
  await Promise.all(chunk.map(async(projectName) => {
    await collectProjectData(projectName);
  });
}
```

Comment: This isn't multithreaded at all. node.js processes are single-threaded by design. This is just async.

Comment: @ShioT good point and very true. Because it is by design, it is rather difficult to properly do multithreading. 

The easiest way would be to have multiple instances of the service running sharing the workload, which in this case might not be the best solution.

NodeJS, however, does support async operations fully, which in most cases eliminates the need for extra threads.

I considered OP's main problem as his/her code being slow, they just happen to jump to the conclusion that multithreading will solve the slowness. Async operations are perfectly suited for this use-case.

Comment: In the case that multithreading wouldn't solve the snowness at all, I don't think OP would want to do this either. You are saying that OP is looking for a solution that doesn't exist while giving them something else that doesn't help OP or answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Promise.map
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html

that way you can control the level of concurrency as you wish like this:

```
await Promise.map(projectNames, collectProjectData, {concurrency: 3})
```

Comment: This isn't multithreaded at all. node.js processes are single-threaded by design. This is just async.

Comment: The "collectProjectData" is interacting with a DB and is not cpu bound. therefore the correct way is to handle it async. no need for multithreading.

Comment: Say it in the answer!